(How) Should we customize the "Ask Question" page?
As seen on Meta.SE, The new ask page is now live on the network!
There are many options for each SE site to customize this page:

What's per-site customizable, and what's the procedure to get it live?
As you can see, any existing custom guidance on "How to ask," "How to
  tag," or any custom error or warning messages your site may already
  have in place will still be there, and will still be customizable with
  the same restraints (basic HTML, using paragraphs, lists, links) as
  before:

The "welcome modal" for new askers (seen with the default text in screenshot 1), everything between the title and "Before you
  post..." (this is only custom on 4 sites at the moment, [such as
  EL&U][14]).
The full contents of the "Draft your question" sidebar (seen with the default text in screenshot 2, and with custom text in
  screenshot 3).
The text in the tag popover, between "Tags help the right people..." and the bullet points (seen with custom text in screenshot
  2, and with the default text on screenshot 3).
The above three have no character limits, aside from "within reason."
The placeholder text in the title field (text only; seen with the default text in screenshot 2, and with custom text on screenshot
  3).
The warning text shown in the "Review your question" sidebar, regex-based (seen with the default text in screenshot 4, and with
  custom text on screenshot 5).
Tag-related error messages and warnings, regex-based (seen with custom error text in screenshot 4, with the default text on screenshot
  5,  and with a tag warning
  here).
The warning and error messages described in the two bullet points above have a limit of 1000 characters.

These can only be edited by staff, so the process to get them live is
  as described [here][15]:

Create a Meta post on the appropriate Meta site, and discuss it with your community. 
Once a consensus is reached, a mod should escalate it to the CM team. Generally speaking, the "contact us" form is the best way to go,
  though a ping in chat can sometimes work too (the most that could
  happen is we ask you to use the form).
Unless there are any outstanding issues, the CMs should be able to get to it Soon™.


Do we have any change requests to the existing setup, and if so, what are they?
